# Show nested value entity in textbox on databinding (c# - winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, nested, bindingsource

I have an entity with others entities inside.
Per example, Entity A has entities B and C.

So, I want to show in a text box the value of A.B.SomeProperty when I set a datasource for bindindsource.
Is it possible with a workaround?
tks

Answer (score 1):

```
textBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource, "B.SomeProperty");
```

You have to ensure that B property is not null.